# Delete the elements of a array with a mask

Tags: python, numpy

I want to delete the elements of an array with a mask. For example:

```
row = 24
col = 24
size = row * col
a = numpy.ones((size))
mask = numpy.empty((col), dtype=numpy.bool)
```

The values of the `mask` are `False` or `True`.
If `mask[x] = True`, Then the element of `a[x * row:(x + 1) * row]` should be deleted.
**PS: In my case one index value corresponds one block elements of `a`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through this syntax you can delete the element of array

```
smaller_array =np.delete(array,index)
```

array indicates the array values
index indicates the position of the elements

Comment: In my case. one index refers to one block elements of the original Array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had got it wrong. Here it is one way to do it, using list comprehension though:

```
idx_delete=np.unique(np.concatenate([np.arange(x*row,row*(x+1)) for x in xrange(row) if mask[x]]))
np.delete(a,idx_delete)
```

Comment: I want to delete a[x*rows : (x+1)*rows]